# User posts two answers, what's the best course of action?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, duplicate-answers

Reference question: [CSS selector code last element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16413499/1313143)

<s>I don't know how long it will last</s> (update: he edited his older answer) but this user "Nathan Lee" posts two answers.

First he posts a generic solution that aids the OP but isn't adapted to the specific code in the question. A couple of minutes later he posts another answer that looks very similar, but is directly adapted for the code of the question.

I wanted to downvote his older answer which I previously upvoted, but that vote is locked. I left a comment on his newer answer that he should remove his older, because what he is doing is bad. What should I do more? Which of the two answers should I flag, if that is necessary?

Comment: He deleted it in response to your comment already.

Comment: "deleted by owner 3 mins ago"

Comment: Okay, but suppose he did not: what should I do?

Comment: Posting two answers, if different enough, is not necessarily inappropriate.

Comment: It looks like both are same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Okay, but suppose he did not: what should I do?

Flag it for moderator attention, and point out that the answer is a duplicate of one he had already posted on the same question.

It's no big deal, it looks like it is a simple mistake, nothing more - it is unlikely that he would have left it there (unless he was new and had no idea how to remove it).

Comment: @Lucifer then that is your answer - do nothing, the system will pick it up. I'm not sure which review queue it will get posted in to though. In any case, looks like your question is answered - the feature already exists to deal with it.

Comment: Opps, you are already a mod. Hmmm then sure your answer is correct. My mistake. ( +1 )

Comment: @Lucifer Yeah, but not a mod on SO - they can have activity and occurrences you just don't see on some other sites, hence why I'm unsure of which queue (community or mod) the flagged answer goes in to.